# Sort nulls to bottom in sqlite AND use pre-existing index

Tags: sql, sqlite, jdbc

I have a sqlite database table presented as a user-interface table. The user can click column headers to specify a multi-column sort order. Some columns are text, others are integers or reals.

The table can be large enough that creating a temporary index introduces an observable and annoying delay. So I'd like to use a pre-existing index. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX MyTable_name on MyTable ( name, color, position );
```

But I also want nulls and blanks to sort to the bottom. So my query can contain an ORDER BY like this:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ((name IS NULL) OR (name = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, name ASC,
    (CASE WHEN ((color IS NULL) OR (color = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, color ASC,
    (CASE WHEN ((position IS NULL) OR (position = '')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, position ASC
```

That doesn't match the simpler index, so sqlite will create an appropriate temporary index.

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN MyTable
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

**How can I both sort nulls to the bottom and use a pre-existing index?**

It's occurred to me that I could hack this by shadowing every column with a precomputed 1 or 0 value, and add those shadow columns both to the index and the ORDER BY. I'm hoping there's a simpler solution.

Comment: I solved this issue by replacing each CASE with the name of a shadow column with a precomputed 1 or 0 value, and including those columns in CREATE INDEX. Good thing: now uses my non-temporary index. Bad thing: twice as many columns.